# How to correctly in MVVM get the retrofit data from the repository to the viewmodel?

Tags: android, mvvm, retrofit

I know how to get data from the spinners and then pass data from the api to the repository, but how to get data from repository to viewmodel correctly in the mvvm in my case?
In the repository I have Currency object in the MutableLiveData, and I want to get data from this object.

```
public class MainViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

private CurrencyRepository currencyRepository;
public final ObservableField<String> from = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableField<String> to = new ObservableField<>();
public final ObservableFloat value = new ObservableFloat();
private MutableLiveData<Currency> currencyLiveData;
String TAG = "MAIN";

public MainViewModel(Application application) {
   super(application);
   currencyRepository = new CurrencyRepository(application);
}

public void calculateRate() {
    currencyRepository.getCurrency(String.valueOf(from.get()), String.valueOf(to.get()), ApiClient.KEY);

//In this method I'm passing kind of the currency from the spinners in my view
}
```

Repository:

```
public class CurrencyRepository {

private ApiInterface apiInterface;
private  String apiKey = ApiClient.KEY;

public CurrencyRepository(Application application) {
   apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient();
}

public LiveData<Currency> getCurrency(String base, String target, String apiKey) {

    final MutableLiveData<Currency> data = new MutableLiveData<>();
    apiInterface.getCurrentCurrency(base, target, apiKey).enqueue(new Callback<Currency>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Currency> call, Response<Currency> response) {
            data.setValue(response.body());

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Currency> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
    return data;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Good approuch is doing that stuff with ReactiveX. In Java it is RxJava. [Here you could see an example with description](https://android.jlelse.eu/implementing-rxjava2-retrofit2-for-better-performance-during-api-calls-fe1c53e1f939).

Comment: What about Livedata? There is some way?

Answer (score 0):

The concept with MVVM is that the View has a reference to the ViewModel but the ViewModel doesn't have a reference to the View. The same applies down the tree for the relationship between ViewModel and Repository.

You are using LiveData for the repository which is great. You'll need to get the ViewModel to subscribe to the LiveData and then stream your changing data to any observers (the ViewModel)

I've found this is a great video to watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ugpC98LcNqA&t=6s

You can also checkout some of Googles examples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture